# ASP.NET MVC - Throwing a 403 or 401 in an Action Method Bypasses Custom Error View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my action method I'm trying to validate if the user has access to the resource they are requesting.  If not, I want to throw an exception.

If I just throw new Exception("you are not authorized"), it works perfectly.  My custom error view is then shown.

If, however, I throw new HttpException(403, "you are not authorized") it bypasses my custom error view, and shows a generic white error page saying:

"An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated."

My custom errors section in web.config looks like this:

```xml
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="NotFoundError" />
    </customErrors>
```

I have a globally-registered CustomHandleErrorAttribute whose OnException method looks like this:

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);
        LogError(filterContext);

        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl != "/")
            {
                emailError(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, I am using ASP.NET Identity for authentication/authorization; I'm not sure if that matters.

Thanks.

Aaron

Comment: What does your custom error page look like? If you're using MVC's `HandleErrorInfo` class, it will be null for an HTTP error.

Comment: Did you try adding an <error> tag with statusCode=403?

Comment: The Model is, in fact, a HandleErrorInfo object.  But I'm not referencing it in the View.  I pulled it out as a test, and I still get the same result.  Also, the Error action in my Error Controller never gets hit.

Comment: @RyanBennett Yes I did.  Same result.

Comment: Is your ErrorController decorated with the `AllowAnonymous` attribute? Since it is an HTTP error, the user won't be authenticated.

Comment: Error Controller is not decorated with [Authorize] so AllowAnonymous isn't necessary.